# UIImagePicker Ipad IOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller, image-gallery

I want to upload image with both camera and gallery in IPAD. But in IOS 6, When I try to choose from gallery application is crashed. Here below is my code:

```
    picker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;

    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                         initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(44, 6, 111, 111) inView:self.view.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];  //When app enter this line , app starts to crash.
```

I have checked with  self.view instead of self.view.superview too. I got the same error.Actually , app crashed in this line . I didnt see any specific error in debug console.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you paste where the crash that you receive?

Answer (score 2):

i guess `self.view.superview` is wrong line, a popover should be part of self view, not its superview. Give any specific frame or any view element frame

Comment: Retro ,Actually , i have checked before with self.view too. But i got the same error.
Szu ,  **[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(44, 6, 111, 111) inView:self.view.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];  ** the crash is in this line

Comment: try this [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(44, 6, 111, 111) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

Comment: Please read my edited question and comment .. I applied this already. But still i got crash

Comment: what's the crash log stack?

Comment: That is the problem. I cant see the reason of crash in the log. Just while debugging , the app crashes in this line that i said.

Comment: did you check in instrument?

Comment: No! How can i check from therE?

Comment: just run with zombie enable in instrument

Comment: Can you please let me know , How can I check from there? Im going -->XCode->Developer Tool>>Instruments and selecting zombie. But I cant see anything

Comment: i didnt understand what u mean

Comment: i guess you need to read a tutorial on instrument and how to use it